# Moderncv package - cventry date width

Tags: moderncv

I am writing my CV using `moderncv` package, everythig is nice but I have a problem with `\cventry` command. I have something like this:

[image] (it means 2010 - now)

I would want to have this in one line, rather than in two lines. I tried looking into the `moderncv` style files but with no success. What can I do to achieve the effect I want?

Comment: You could also write `\llap{2010--now}` to get onto one line. In this case you lap the text the left without taking any official space.

Answer (score 15):

It seems I found the solution to my problem, if I add this line

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}
```

and tweak a bit with lengths I can get the results that I wanted.