# Date column in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, datetime

I am writing my cv and with the following code

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\firstname{C}
\familyname{N}
\title{Curriculum vit\ae{}}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}          
\usepackage[english]{babel}              

\begin{document}


\section{studies}

\cventry{Dec 01, 2010 -- Jan 01, 2011}{student assistant}{}{}{}{chair of statistics xxxx \newline student assistant as a tutor of statistics 2 }
\cventry{Jul 31, 2008 -- Sep 30, 2011}{matriculation Bachelor of Science x}{}{}{}{university of x}





\end{document}
```

I produce the following output

[image: t1]

What I don't like is the line breaking of the date. In the first entry the "-" is in the second line and in the second entry it is in the first line. So I would prefer a more uniform formatting, so that the "-" is either in the first line or in the next line, but always the same and not switching. Any ideas?

Comment: May be you could find useful [modertimeline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/putting-a-timeline-for-dates-in-moderncv).

Comment: You can use ties `~` to provide non-breakable spaces and write: `Dec~01,~2010~-- Jan 01, 2011`

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59044/moderncv-package-cventry-date-width if you want to adjust the width of the date column.